# Scraping with Selenium. VS code shows no errors but when program runs nothing happens

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a capstone project for school and I am running into an issue where the program runs but nothing happens. I have the correct webdriver and my python is up to date. I am getting really frustrated so any help would be great. I will paste the code below.  I will also put an image of what happens when I run it I always have to force end the program.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

import pandas as pd

import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

import schedule

departure_flight_inputs={'Departure': " ORD",
               'Arrival': " LAS",
               'Date': "Jun 1, 2024"}

return_flight_inputs={'Departure': " LAS",
               'Arrival': " ORD",
               'Date': "Jun 8, 2024"}

def find_cheapest_flights(flight_info):
    PATH = R"C:\Users\theya\OneDrive\Desktop\FlightPriceTracker\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)

    leaving_from = flight_info['Departure']
    going_to = flight_info['Arrival']
    trip_date = flight_info['Date']
    
    
    #Go to Expedia
    driver.get( "https://expedia.com")

   #Click on Flights
   # The flight_xpath represent the flight button on expedia
    flight_xpath = "//a[@class='uitk-tab-anchor uitk-tab-anchor-selected' and @aria-controls='search_form_product_selector_flights']"
    flight_element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, flight_xpath))
        )
    flight_element.click()
    time.sleep(0.2)

      #Click on One-Way. IBecause it is easier this way.
    oneway_xpath = "//a[@class='uitk-tab-anchor uitk-tab-anchor-selected' and @aria-controls='FlightSearchForm_ONE_WAY']"
    one_way_element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, oneway_xpath))
        )
    one_way_element.click()
    time.sleep(0.2)

   #Part 1: Flying From, Flying To, Departure Date, Return Date
    
    #**********************  Complete Leaving From Portion  **********************
    leaving_from_xpath = "//button[@aria-label='Leaving from' and @data-stid='origin_select-dialog-trigger']"
    leaving_from_element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, leaving_from_xpath))
        )
    leaving_from_element.clear
    leaving_from_element.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    leaving_from_element.send_keys(leaving_from)
    
    time.sleep(1) #Need this otherwise it will be too fast for the broswer
    leaving_from_element.send_keys(Keys.DOWN, Keys.RETURN)
    #**********************  Complete Leaving From Portion  **********************
    
    
    
    #**********************  Complete Going To Portion  **********************
    going_to_xpath = "//button[@aria-label='Going to' and @data-stid='destination_select-dialog-trigger']"
    going_to_element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, going_to_xpath))
        )
    going_to_element.clear
    going_to_element.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    going_to_element.send_keys(going_to)
    
    time.sleep(1) #Need this otherwise it will be too fast for the broswer
    going_to_element.send_keys(Keys.DOWN, Keys.RETURN) #Go down on item and click on it
    #**********************  Complete Going To Portion  **********************
    
    
    
    #**********************  Complete Departure Date Portion  **********************
    departing_box_xpath = '//button[contains(@aria-label,"Departing")]'
    
    depart_box_element = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, departing_box_xpath))
        )
    
    depart_box_element.click() #Click on the departure box
    time.sleep(2)
    
    
    #Find the current date. WILL arrow through too
    trip_date_xpath = '//button[contains(@aria-label,"{}")]'.format(trip_date)
    departing_date_element = ""
    while departing_date_element == "":
        try:
            departing_date_element = WebDriverWait(driver,3).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, trip_date_xpath))
            )
            departing_date_element.click() #Click on the departure date
        except TimeoutException:
           departing_date_element=""
           next_month_xpath = "//button[@data-stid='uitk-calendar-navigation-controls-next-button'][2]"
           driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_month_xpath).click()
           time.sleep(1)
    
    depart_date_done_xpath = "//button[@data-stid='apply-date-selector' and text()='Done']"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(depart_date_done_xpath).click()
    #**********************  Complete Departure Date Portion  **********************
    
    
    #**********************  Click Search  **********************
    search_button_xpath =  "//button[@id='search_button' and @type='submit' and @aria-label='Search' and text()='Search']"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_button_xpath).click()
    time.sleep(15) #Need to let the page load properly
    #**********************  Click Search  **********************

     #Part 2: Setting Conditions for our flight
    
    #**********************  Check for Nonstop Flights Sorted by Lowest Price  **********************
    nonstop_flight_xpath = "//label[@for='NUM_OF_STOPS-0-qoo' and span[@class='uitk-checkbox-label-content']]"
    one_stop_flight_xpath = "//label[@for='NUM_OF_STOPS-1-8qb' and span[@class='uitk-checkbox-label-content')]]"
    
    
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(nonstop_flight_xpath)) > 0:
        
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(nonstop_flight_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(5)
        
        #Check if there are available flights
        available_flights = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Select and show fare information ')]")
        if len(available_flights) >  0:
            if len(available_flights) == 1: #Don't have to sort by prices here
                flights = [(item.text.split(",")[0].split('for')[-1].title(),
                            item.text.split(",")[1].title().replace("At",":"),
                            item.text.split(",")[2].title().replace("At",":"),
                            item.text.split(",")[3].title().replace("At",":")) for item in available_flights[0:5]]

            else:
                #Sort by lowest prices
                driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//select[@id='sort-filter-dropdown-SORT']/option[@value='PRICE_INCREASING']").click()
                time.sleep(5)
                flights = [(item.text.split(",")[0].split('for')[-1].title(),
                            item.text.split(",")[1].title().replace("At",":"),
                            item.text.split(",")[2].title().replace("At",":"),
                            item.text.split(",")[3].title().replace("At",":")) for item in available_flights[0:5]]
            
            
            print("Conditions satisfied for: {}:{}, {}:{}, {}:{}".format("Departure",leaving_from,
                                                             "Arrival",going_to,
                                                             "Date",trip_date))
            driver.quit()
            return flights
    else:
        print('Not all conditions could be met for the following: "{}:{}, {}:{}, {}:{}'.format("Departure",leaving_from,
                                                                                             "Arrival",going_to,
                                                                                             "Date",trip_date))
        driver.quit()
        return []
    
    

    #**********************  Check for Nonstop Flights Sorted by Lowest Price  **********************



def send_email():
    #Get return values
    departing_flights = find_cheapest_flights(departure_flight_inputs)
    return_flights = find_cheapest_flights(return_flight_inputs)

    #Put it into a dataframe to visualize this more easily
    df = pd.DataFrame(departing_flights + return_flights)
    
    if not df.empty: #Only send an email if we have actual flight info
        email = open('theyamarlyons@gmail.com').read()
        password=open('$mallJoke11').read()
        
        msg = EmailMessage()
        
        msg['Subject'] = "Python Flight Info! {} --> {}, Departing: {}, Returning: {}".format(departure_flight_inputs['Departure'], departure_flight_inputs['Arrival'], departure_flight_inputs['Date'],return_flight_inputs['Date'])
        
        msg['From'] = email
        msg['To'] = email
        
        msg.add_alternative('''\
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <body>
                    {}
                </body>
            </html>'''.format(df.to_html()), subtype="html")
    
            
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465) as smtp:
            smtp.login(email,password)
            smtp.send_message(msg)
    

schedule.clear()
schedule.every(30).minutes.do(send_email)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I tried upating my Chrome and the Chromedriver I was using because I thought maybe thats why it was not working. I also checked for any bad indents but could not find any.

Comment: Try debugging your code and going through the execution of your script step by step. It will help you understand where things go wrong.

Comment: I suspect that `schedule.every(30).minutes` runs your function in 30 minutes, not right now.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks a lot I was able to fix that thanks to you. But now the program runs to the point where it opens the departure information but it does not type anything in it just times out.